# Macro stops at `ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True`

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automated the process by using VBs to auto run the macro without opening the Excel.

I have tested the Macro and it works fine if the workbook is opened. However, when I run the Macro through the VBs Script, the Maro stops at `ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True`. Does anybody knows why?

**My Macro**

```
Sub sendEmail()
MsgBox "sendEmail Start!"    'Appears when run VBs

   ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
   MsgBox "EnvelopeVisible True!" 'did not appear when run VBs

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").MailEnvelope
    MsgBox "MailEnvelope Prepare!"
      .Introduction = "Message"
      .Item.To = "To who it may concern"
      .Item.Subject = ""
      .Item.Send
      MsgBox "MailEnvelope Send!"
    End With

  ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
  MsgBox "sendEmail Done!"
End Sub
```

**My VBs**

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Folder\Ver 6.xlsm'!AutoEmail.sendEmail"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

I'm running the VBs to activate the Macro

Comment: If you step through it with `F8` does it run that line and then just exit the sub?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, When the workbook is opened. The macro works good. Just when I run the macro using the VBs, it stops at `MsgBox "EnvelopeVisible True!"`. The `MsgBox "sendEmail Start!"` Did appear

Comment: "...when I run the macros using the VBs..." - what do you mean? Instead of `ThisWorkbook`, perhaps actually assign a workbook using the filename/path?

Comment: At first I also think it's because of `ThisWorkbook`. I tried with another macro `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shee1") MsgBox"Checking"`. The **Checking** did appear. This cause me to think that's because of the `EnvelopeVisible`, but I'm not positive about it.

Comment: hmm I think it's because when the macro is running, `ThisWorkbook` is referring to `Ver 6.xlsm`.  is that the book you're trying to actually run it on?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, that's the workbook with the `sendEmail` macro

Comment: In the VBS add line `objExcel.Visible = True` immediately after `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` and try.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thanks, It works after it opens the excel temporarily and close it. Do you mind post as answer and explain a little why this occurs?

Comment: @Max It was a hunch based on issue description. I have posted explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add following line to VBS:

`objExcel.Visible = True`

just after

`Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

It is based on a simple clue that your issue description gave.

- Excel Macro works if it is opened and run from Excel.
- It halts if it is being run from the VBS

When I looked at the MSDN explanation for this property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-envelopevisible-property-excel

It says

> True if the e-mail composition header and the envelope toolbar are both visible. Read/write Boolean .

So to make it work we need to make the parent object visible i.e. Excel.Application.